# VBA Hide row Calculate event

Tags: vba, events

I want to create an excel file with 3 sheets.
Sheet 1: Overview
Sheet 2: Products 1, which has 2 columns: Product and amount
Sheet 3: Products 2, which has 2 columns: Product and amount

The idea is that when I enter an amount (e.g. row 2, value 3), it will show up on sheet 1 (Overview). And it will be removed from sheet 1 when the amount is 0.

So I now added links of sheet 2 and sheet 3 on sheet 1.
On sheet 1 I use the Calculate event, so every time the formula changes it fires an event.
In this event I used a for / next loop (1 row till last row), which works fine if you do not have that much products on sheet 1.
But if you have about 150 products it takes about 3 seconds, which is too long.

Is there a way to determine which cell has been changed on sheet 1?

Or is there another way to do this....

Comment: "Is there a way to determine which cell has been changed on sheet 1?" To detect a change, and where it happens, you can use `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` Then you only update for the `target` which is a variable that returns the range that triggered the event.

Comment: @ChristoferWeber, the Change_event is not triggered on sheet 1 when you make changes on sheet 2 or 3... That is way I had in mind to used the Calculate_event

Comment: Right, you aren't changing sheet 1, the value is changing with the formula. But if you are already handling the data with formulas, do you even need the macro? What does it do?

Comment: @ChristoferWeber
Might have found the way to go. Disadvantage is the I need to add rows for the 3th sheet (on sheet 1 I first have row 1 to x for sheet 2 products and row x to y for sheet 3 products).
And if I want to select multiple cell selection on sheet 2 or 3 and delete the value, I get an error.

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
If Target.Value > 0 Then     ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("OverView").Rows(Target.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else           ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Overview").Rows(Target.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

End Sub